# Javascript Typewriter Effect using Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, timer

I am trying to make a typewriter effect in javascript using array. At first I hardcoded a string in the array and the effect worked properly. Later, i tried doing the same thing with user input but it would not work.

**This is the hardcoded version:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr=new Array()
var start=0;
var end=start + 1;
arr[0]="Hello";
function write()
{
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML + arr[0].slice(start,end);
        start++;
        end=start + 1;
        if (start < 5) {
            write();
        }
    }, 500);
}
onload=write();
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the version in which I'm trying to get user input:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr=new Array()
var start=0;
var end=start + 1;
arr[0]=document.getElementById('word').innerHTML;
function write()
{
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML + arr[0].slice(start,end);
        start++;
        end=start + 1;
        if (start < 5) {
            write();
        }
    }, 500);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="word">
<br>
<a href="javascript:write()">Click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me what changes i should make in my coding so that the version with user input works properly.

Comment: I love it, and I think I was looking something like this, thanx also :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `value` property instead of `innerHTML`:

```
arr[0]=document.getElementById('word').value;
```

And put that inside the `write` function, so that you get the value when the link is clicked instead of before the element even exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr=new Array()
var start=0;
var end=start + 1;
arr[0]="Hello";
function write()
{
    setTimeout(function() {
        //document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML + arr[0].slice(start,end);
        document.getElementById("word").value=document.getElementById("word").value + arr[0].slice(start,end);
        start++;
        end=start + 1;
        if (start < 5) {
            write();
        }
    }, 500);
}
onload=write();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" value="" id="word">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short:
Usually - To get the current value of input (including select, textarea, radio, etc.) get it from attribute value, innerHTML from others.

No need to use an array :)
You can write a lot less with the same effect.

```
// `str` is the string to write to on `target` element.
function write(str, target){


  var attr = ~"input,textarea".indexOf( target.tagName.toLowerCase() )? 'value' : 'innerHTML',
  //attr - element attribute which contains its value/html
  //if it isn't a input or textarea `attr` should be innerHTML;

  start=0,
  interval = setInterval(function() {
        target[attr] += str.substr(start++,1); //get one character starting from `start` 
        if( start >= str){
            clearInterval( interval );
        }
    }, 500);
  target[attr]  = ''; //clear the current text on target element.
};
write('hello', document.getElementById('word') ); 
//  write('hello', document.body );
```

Comment: No, you don't get it from the HTML attribute, you get it from the DOM *property* `value`