# Animate array from user input like typewriter (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I suppose my question is a bit similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920590/javascript-typewriter-effect-using-array), but I can't really work out how to do my specific need from it. I'm building a very basic text adventure, and I'd like the returned text - after the user has entered a command - to be returned in a typewriter style. Here's a snippet of my commands so far (there'll be a lot more, I don't mind that this will be built in a bit of a tedious way)

```
    <script>

textIn  = document.getElementById("input-textbox");
textOut = document.getElementById("output-textbox");

function process(input) {
    if (input == "hi") { textOut.innerHTML += "Hello to you too!<br><br>"; }
    else if (input == "exit") { textOut.innerHTML += "No."; }
}

function go() {
    var input = textIn.value;
    textIn.value = "";
    var output = process(input);
    textOut.value += output + "\n";
}

</script>
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="output-textbox">
  Returned text goes here.
</div>
<form onSubmit="go();return false;">
<input id="input-textbox" name="command" value="" autofocus="autofocus"/>
</form>
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance! This solution doesn't need to be beautiful, code wise, nor very nifty. It just has to work, I have no standards at all with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a timeout for each character inside a loop, with each timeout being a bit later than the last. See: https://jsfiddle.net/fswam77j/1/

```
var outputEl = document.querySelector('#output-textbox');
var charInterval = 50; // ms between characters appearing

function showOutput(text) {
  outputEl.innerHTML = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    showChar(text, i);
  }
}

function showChar(text, i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      outputEl.innerHTML += text[i];
    }, i * charInterval);
}

showOutput('this is an example');
```

process the input:

```
function process(input) {
    if (input == "hi") { 
        showOutput("Hello to you too!"); 
    }
    else if (input == "exit") { 
        showOutput("No."); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds good so far! But bear with me, I'm not too knowledgeable about javascript... How do I get the "process(input)" etc thing into this?

Comment: i've added another snippet to my answer above. feel free to select it or another answer if you think it may help others

Comment: Thanks so much! Quick follow up question: how would I add html tags in the output? For instance, I have multiple sentences in a return and I'd like those to have a linebreak after each one. Is that possible? Like "Hello to you too!<br>How are you?"

Answer (score 1):

Based on William B's answer, here is a more condensed version:

https://jsfiddle.net/sators/4wra3y1p/1/

HTML

```
<div id="output-typewriter"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function typewriterText(text) {
    var outEl = document.querySelector('#output-typewriter');
    var interval = 50; // ms between characters appearing
    outEl.innerHTML = '';
    text.split('').forEach(function(char, i){
      setTimeout(function () {
        outEl.innerHTML += char;
      }, i * interval);
    });
}

typewriterText('this is an example');
```

Comment: Thanks for the condensed version! I'll have to accept William B's answer though, since he expanded on my question a bit. But this looks good!